# Is this integral finite and how does it decay to zero?

Tags: integration, limits-and-convergence

I would like to know if the following is convergent/finite (it represents a bound from a truncated Legendre series approximation)
\begin{equation}
\varepsilon_n \leq \int_{-1}^1 \left(\int_{n\gg 1}^\infty \dfrac{1}{k(1 + k^2(1-x^2))^{1/4}}\mathrm{d}k\right)^4 \mathrm{d}x. 
\end{equation}
where I suspect 
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \varepsilon_n = \mathcal{O}(n^{-2})\qquad ?$$

With a change of variables $\tilde{k} = k\sqrt{1-x^2}$ we can re-arrange the inner integrand to be
\begin{equation}
\int_{\tilde{n}}^\infty \dfrac{1}{\tilde{k}(1 + \tilde{k}^2)^{1/4}}\mathrm{d}\tilde{k}.
\end{equation}
This can be integrated analytically to give the summation of an $\arctan$ and $\mathrm{arctanh}$, but Mathematica evaluates this to a nasty function which I can't seem to get anything sensible out of when using `AsymptoticIntegrate`.

**Ultimately I'm hoping the integral is finite, and if so, then how fast does it decay to zero as $n\to \infty$.**

Comment: That the inner integral is finite - doesn't it follow from the ratio test, say by comparing with $1/klog(k)$?

Comment: When $\tilde{k}$ is large, we have $1 + \tilde{k}^2 \sim \tilde{k}^2$ and so your $\tilde{k}$ integral is approximately $\int_{\tilde{n}}^\infty \tilde{k}^{-3/2}\,d\tilde{k} = 2\tilde{n}^{-1/2}$.  Then the fourth power explains how you end up with $n^{-2}$ in the end.

Comment: @auniket The inner integral is finite a.s.

Comment: @NateEldredge $\tilde{k}$ is not large everywhere, and if I neglect the "$1 + \ldots$" then the outer integration produces a divergent integral. Hence I need to keep the small "$1+\ldots$" term to try and keep everything finite.